# Run-time error "1004": Macro "getUnits" can not be run. macro must not be accessible in this worksheet or all the macros are forbidden

Tags: excel, vba

i have created a macro via recording that works perfectely on my comp, but when i send it to other colleagues, they can not run it for the issue described in the title (I have translated the issue from Slovak to English). Below is the VBN code (there will be some text in Slovak):

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
' Výpočet doby návratnosti
'
' Klávesová skratka: Ctrl+r
'
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
Sheets("Doba návratnosti").Select
Application.Run "getUnits"
Range("G24").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("G24").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D24")
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-1
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-1
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-1
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-1
Sheets("Výsledky").Select
Application.Run "getUnits"
End Sub
```

I have already tried the Open and Repair option, there is not a GWXL97.XLA file, "Trust access to the VBA project object model" is marked and my sheet is anprotected, Stellar Repair shut after scanning my document, openAI couldnt help. i am not advanced in macros, but  dont get it why (while creating a macro via recording) the automatically generated name of the macro is getUnits while in the Name Field it is Makro1.

I am looking forward to your solutions.

Comment: Your automatically generated name is `Makro1` - first line of your code.  While recording did you execute another macro called `getUnits`?  This line implies that `Application.Run "getUnits"`.  The getUnits code must also be accessible on the other machines.  [Application.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Run)

Comment: While recording I executed a Goal Seek via What-If Analysis, but definitelly not another macro. The above is the only macro in my document, so I have no idea what is "getUnits"

Comment: By the way I tried to create another macro (the same reporting method) using the Solver tool instead of Goal Seek and the same line (Application.Run "getUnits") was generated in my macro. And once again, it works for me, but doesnt for my colleagues.

Comment: Not sure what `getUnits` is then - can't find it in a google search.  When I record a goalseek macro it doesn't give me that line.  Try changing all your code to `Sub Makro1(): With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Doba návratnosti"): .Range("G24").GoalSeek goal:=0, changingcell:=.Range("D24"): End With: End Sub
` - the `:` in the code can be replaced with line breaks.

Comment: We've already figured it out. It was caused by the different excel versions :/ among us. In the other version the getUnits function or macro or whatever it is, is not called in apostrophes but simply without them. That was all. But thanks Darren for Your effort.

Comment: Glad you get there in the end.  You can still tidy up your code by removing the `ScrollWorkbookTabs` lines - they just [Scrolls through the workbook tabs at the bottom of the window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.scrollworkbooktabs).  It just recorded you moving around the workbook - not needed in the code.  The `Application.CutCopyMode = False` could also be removed.